# Equipartition theorem. Neglecting one rotational degree of freedom

Tags: statistical-mechanics

My teacher said that a rotational degree of freedom for a molecule in a gas can be neglected if the associated moment of inertia is very small, because the associated frequency of rotation will be very high. 
Could somebody explain this to me ?

Comment: I cannot reconcile the answers of the "possible duplicate" with the fact that the frequency of rotation is very high.. Shouldn't the reason be rather that the spacing between different allowed frequencies is very high ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some rotational degree of freedom the component of the momentum of inertia $I$ is very small, the component of angular momentum is of the order of $I\omega$, where $\omega$ is the relevant angular velocity. On the other hand, for lower excited levels (for this degree of freedom) this component of angular momentum is of the order of $\hbar$, therefore, $\omega$ is of the order of $\frac{\hbar}{I}$. The energy for these levels is of the order of $I\omega^2$, therefore, it is of the order of $\frac{\hbar^2}{I}$. For these levels to be significantly filled, this energy should be at least comparable to the temperature (in the energy units) $kT$. As $I$ is very small, this does not happen at reasonable temperatures (or, in other words, it only happens at temperatures that are much higher than the temperatures at which other rotational degrees of freedom become important).

Comment: Thank you! Just a few questions: does your answer imply that the spacing between the lower energy levels is h/I ? Does it also imply that in order to apply the equipartition theorem one must suppose that the energy can vary continuously, which happens only for "significantly" filled states ?

Comment: @Pao : If you measure the spacing in energy units, the spacing is **of the order of** $\frac{\hbar^2}{I}$. The equipartition theorem can only be derived in classical statistical physics. Its results are approximately correct for degrees of freedom of a quantum system where the relevant spacing for the degrees of freedom is much smaller than $kT$.